# Chart .js Method is not implemented

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

So the problem is this. My x is not showing(time), I can't see time of the chart or (x), I am getting this error  `Error: This method is not implemented: either no adapter can be found or an incomplete integration was provided.` I have tried many things, I have turned the internet upside down, where I have found some blogs about adding ticks to xAxes that would help, but it did not help.
Please, someone, help me
Chart.js

```
import { Chart, registerables } from 'chart.js';
Chart.register(...registerables);

const determineTimeFormat = (
  timeFormat: string,
  day: any,
  week: any,
  year: any
) => {
  switch (timeFormat) {
    case "24h":
      return day;
    case "7d":
      return week;
    case "1y":
      return year;
    default:
      return day;
  }
};

interface Props {
  data: any
}

const ChartData: React.FC<Props> = ({ data }) => {
  const chartCanvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement | null>(null);
  const { day, week, year, detail } = data;
  const [timeFormat, setTimeFormat] = useState("24h");
  const [isRebuildingCanvas, setIsRebuildingCanvas] = useState(false);
  
 

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsRebuildingCanvas(true);
  }, [timeFormat]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isRebuildingCanvas) {
      setIsRebuildingCanvas(false);
    }
  }, [isRebuildingCanvas]);

  useEffect(() => {
      if (chartCanvasRef && chartCanvasRef.current && detail) {
    const chartCanvas = chartCanvasRef.current
    if (isRebuildingCanvas || !chartCanvas) {
      return;
    }
  
    const chartInstance = new Chart(chartCanvasRef.current, {
      type: "line",
      data: {
        datasets: [
          {
            label: `${detail.name} price`,
            data: determineTimeFormat(timeFormat, day, week, year),
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(134,159,152, 1)',
            borderColor: "rgba(174, 305, 194, 0.4",
            pointRadius: 0,
          },
        ],
      },
```

Options

```
  options: {      
        animation: {
          duration: 2000,
        },
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        responsive: true,
        scales: {
          x: 
            {
              type: "time",
            },  
        },
      }
    });
    return () => {
      chartInstance.destroy();
    }
  }}, [day, isRebuildingCanvas,timeFormat, week, year, detail]);
```

Same component

```
 return (
    <div className='chart__container'>
    {renderPrice()}
      {isRebuildingCanvas ? undefined : (
        <canvas ref={chartCanvasRef} id='myChart'></canvas>
      )}
      <button className='time__format' onClick={() => setTimeFormat("24h")}>24h</button>
      <button className='time__format' onClick={() => setTimeFormat("7d")}>7d</button>
      <button className='time__format'  onClick={() => setTimeFormat("1y")}>1y</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ChartData;
```

Comment: which version of char.js are you using? do you have moment.js as dependency?

Comment: @PriyankKachhela  Chart is v3, I don't have moment js

Comment: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#date-adapters
According to this document `The time scale requires both a date library and a corresponding adapter to be present`

Comment: I have installed the adapter(moment), but it did not fixed the problem, is the import good

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According this [document](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#date-adapters)

> The time scale requires both a date library and a corresponding adapter to be present

So if you are using npm

```
npm install moment chartjs-adapter-moment --save-dev
```

and in your files

```
import { Chart } from 'chart.js'
import 'chartjs-adapter-moment';
```

You can use any other adapter described [here](https://github.com/chartjs/awesome#adapters)

Comment: so I can see the x time, but can't see the actual lines in the graph

Comment: Still cant see the actual lines in the canvas

Comment: can you create working demo in https://codesandbox.io or https://stackblitz.com so we can take better look?

Comment: 10 components, everything is connected

Comment: Ohh.. well currently how many datasets are you passing to graph?

Comment: I have updated the rest of the code, How would I approach so that when I press the button to change the graph. X axes(time)  changes on button press, do I have to do it in the options  or

Comment: I think you are only passing one data to chart so maybe that's why it is not showing line chart. Can you try to add more data in `dataSets`

Comment: So, I have changed the type to bar, and I can see the bar

Comment: Okay great. Issue was you are passing only one data in chart and for `line` chart I think atleast 2 data is required otherwise it will not show line.

Comment: Okay, look I could see the bar when (x) type was set to ```timeseries```, but when I put it back to time, I couldn't not see chart, but when was set to timeseries. The actual time/dates were  bugged, everything was merged to one cell